# Scrollbar handles not visible

Tags: javascript, css

The scroll-bar handles aren't visible in my page. I've tried setting overflow-x to auto and scroll for both the #cust1 and #cust2 div's.

I also need five div's to have their horizontal scrolling controlled from just one scroll-bar at the bottom of the page. (Div's #one, #two, #three, #four and #custTimeline)I don't want scroll-bars for each customer div.

Please help. https://jsfiddle.net/c71ytuxz/1/

```js
var c = document.getElementById("custTimeline");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(-90*Math.PI/180);

var baseLoc = 130;
var hours = ["5AM","6AM", "7AM","8AM","9AM","10AM","11AM","12 NOON","1PM","2PM","3PM","4PM","5PM","6PM", "7PM", "8PM", "9PM", "10PM", "11PM", "12PM"];

for(i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
     ctx.fillText(hours[i], -120, baseLoc);
  }  
  else {
     baseLoc += 90;
     ctx.fillText(hours[i], -120, baseLoc);  
  }
}
ctx.restore();
```

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#cust1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 160px;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 150px;
    background: lightgrey;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#one {
    width: 8%;
    height: 150px;
    background: darkgrey;
    float: left;   
    text-align: center;
}
#two {
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
}

#cust2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 320px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 150px;
    background: lightgrey;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#three {
    width: 8%;
    height: 150px;
    background: darkgrey;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
#four {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="custTimeline"
  width = "1900"
  height = "130"
  style = "border:3px solid #aaaaaa;">
</canvas>

<div id="cust1">
    <div id="one"><p>
    Customer 1
    </p></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>

<div id="cust2">
    <div id="three"><p>
    Customer 2
    </p></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `#cust1` has a width of 1500px, the scroll will only appear when its content gets wider than that, and at the moment it is only 8% (`#one`) + 25% + 35px (`#two`) in total.

If you want it to scroll, change this

```
#cust1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 160px;
    width: 100vw;                    /*  changed property  */
    height: 150px;
    background: lightgrey;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#two {
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 1000px;                   /*  changed property  */
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c71ytuxz/3/)

---

Updated based on a comment

To have one scroll update another, here is one way, using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( window ).scroll(function(){
        var position = $( this ).scrollLeft();
        $("#first").scrollLeft(position);
        $("#second").scrollLeft(position);
    });
});
```

Comment: The green areas are arrival time indicators and their supposed to be narrow. The #cust1 and #cust2 div's are set to 1500px each which should have forced the scroll-bars but aren't working.

Comment: @mike That is not how scrollbar works ... since #cust1 and #cust2 have the `òverflow:auto`, they get scrollable (active scrollbars) when their _content_ is bigger than they are wide, not because they are themselves wider than the viewport ... that's why I set them to `100vh` and made the content wider, so you see how it works

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I made it work by creating another long div inside "cust1" and "cust2" called "filler1" and "filler2" and setting their opacity to 0. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0zcz8q5/) Now about the other part of my question, how can I make the scrollbar for "custTimeline" control both "cust1" and "cust2" ?

Comment: I created this proof-of-concept but I can't seam to apply it to the larger example. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1wgv3be/)

Comment: @mike You added the scroll to the wrong object, it should be _window_, and you also need to grab the _position_ value all the time. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1wgv3be/1/) ... updated my answer with this too

Comment: I tried "window" but the bottom scroll bar still isn't moving the others. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4heayxe9/)

Comment: @mike Well, 2 things, first jQuery weren't loaded, second, you need to scroll #cust1 and #cust2, since they are the ones that scroll ... [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4heayxe9/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't understand though, what do you mean "jQuery weren't loaded" ? I don't see any difference between your latest fiddle and the one I posted one comment ago accept that you targeted cust1, cust2 and custTimeline. I didn't try cust1 and cust2 since their positions are supposed to be fixed so I though that wouldn't work but it does.

Comment: @mike Also, when you say _you didn't try cust1 and cust2 since their positions are supposed to be fixed_, that is correct, they are fixed, the scroll does not move the item itself, it moves what's _inside_, hence one set `overflow: scroll` ... hope this makes it clearer how the scroll works